# OpenGL - easy way to switch from Java.awt.Graphics to OpenGL?

Tags: java, opengl, bufferedimage

I am writing a simple 3D engine in Java and i want to switch to OpenGL using JOGL or similar libaries. Currently i render my graphics using BufferedImage and Java.awt.Graphics.

```
private BufferedImage img;
public final int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

private void render() { 
BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
...
}
```

Is there a easy way to port my project to OpenGL or do i need to start from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really any easy switch, because there is so many things to learn within OpenGL like Shaders (GLSL), VAO, VBO, IBO, State changing, buffer binding, etc.

But not only that you also need to learn and understand Matrix and Vector math, where Matrix math for sure can be really difficult. Basically there is a lot of math you need to learn before you can use OpenGL properly.

> Is there a easy way to port my project to OpenGL or do i need to start from scratch?

No not really, because there is a huge difference between `Graphics`/`Graphics2D` and OpenGL. Within `Graphics` you can simply call `drawImage` and then draw whatever `BufferedImage` you've loaded. Where in OpenGL you need to load the image data, create a handle, bind the image data to a buffer, change some states which affect the texture. Not only that you also need to create the vertex data and create and bind it to a `VAO` and/or `VBO`. Then comes the rendering, as in `Graphics` you could simply call one method, where in OpenGL you need to call multiple methods.

Bottom line, if you really want to learn OpenGL, then don't just "GO FOR IT", read all about multiple tings and learn to know them, before you even start programming with it. Trust me you will be doing yourself a favor!

So if you're still up for the task then you could try using either [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/) or [JOGL](http://jogamp.org/).

Also if you begin learning OpenGL, then learn how to use the new methods, and not the old and deprecated once, here are some of them `glMatrixMode()`, `glLoadIdentity()`, `glTranslate()`, `glRotate()`, `glBegin()`, `glEnd()`, `glVertex()`, `glTexCoord()`, `glNormal()`, `glColor()`, and of course when I say `glTranslate()` it goes for all of them `glTranslatef()`, `glTranslated()`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't realise the big difference between them. I think i will start a new OpenGL project with JOGL.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Slick2D](http://slick.ninjacave.com/). It has a very similar API to Java2D and is OpenGL accelerated.

Comment: I used Slick2D once but it seems to be for 2D Games and not 3D Acceloration. It has OpenGL because it uses LWJGL.